# Laravel: How to speed up foreach database update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got this cron job I want to run every month, that assigns random serial number to each active customer.

But it takes so long time to run, with 2000+ active customers and each customer gets 10 random serials, it takes 20k+ update queries to finish the job.

How could I speed this up?

```
foreach($subscriptions as $subscription){
    $updated_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    foreach($games as $game){
        DB::table('serials')
            ->whereNull('user_id')
            ->where('game_id', $game->game_id)
            ->limit(1)
            ->update([
                'user_id'    => $subscription->user_id,
                'updated_at' => $updated_at
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The obvious thing would be to not run a query during each iteration of your loops.  Group the updates together...

Comment: I fail to see how you give 10 random serials to each user. From the query you give each user the serial for each game.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
foreach($subscriptions as $subscription){
    $updated_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    foreach($games as $game){
        DB::table('serials')
            ->whereNull('user_id')
            ->where('game_id', $game->game_id)
            ->limit(1)
            ->updateVeryFast([
                'user_id'    => $subscription->user_id,
                'updated_at' => $updated_at
            ]);
    }
}
```